# Not able to create dynamic array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am new in PHP and in below code $strng value is dynamically created for array.

```
$strng='"Active Life" => "6","Arts & Entertainment" => "4","Beauty & Spa" => "3","Food & Drink" => "1","Hotels" => "10","Local Services" => "8","Nightlife" => "2","Pets" => "9","Public Services" => "7","Shopping" => "5"';
$bussCatry=array($strng);

foreach($bussCatry as $x=>$x_value)
{
    error_log( "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value);      
}
```

but when I am trying to create array I am failing I am getting below out put.
only one key value pair

```
Key=0, 
Value="Active Life" =>"6",
"Arts & Entertainment" =>"4",
"Beauty & Spa" =>"3",
"Food & Drink" =>"1",
"Hotels" =>"10",
"Local Services" =>"8",
"Nightlife" =>"2",
"Pets" =>"9",
"Public Services" =>"7",
"Shopping" =>"5"
```

Comment: `array($strng)` just creates an array whose first element is the value of `$strng`. It doesn't parse it as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out php's [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) syntax.

Try this:

```
$bussCatry = array(
  'Active Life' => '6',
  'Arts & Entertainment' => '4',
  'Beauty & Spa' => '3',
  'Food & Drink' => '1',
  'Hotels' => '10',
  'Local Services' => '8',
  'Nightlife' => '2',
  'Pets' => '9',
  'Public Services' => '7',
  'Shopping' => '5',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, if this really necessary you can try this:

```
eval("\$bussCatry = array({$strng});");
```

Comment: +1 for -1
hehe) I never use eval in my code)
but answer for this question... need write php interpreter?

Comment: missed semicolon, sorry) Edited

Comment: and use other format for string better,
json for example:
`$s='"ka":"va","kb":"vb"';
$bussCatry = json_decode("[{$s}]", 1);
`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array directly assigned values.

```
$bussCatry = array(
        "Active Life" => "6",
        "Arts & Entertainment" => "4",
        "Beauty & Spa" => "3",
        "Food & Drink" => "1",
        "Hotels" => "10",
        "Local Services" => "8",
        "Nightlife" => "2",
        "Pets" => "9",
        "Public Services" => "7",
        "Shopping" => "5"
);
```

Don't convert the `array values` into string with `single quotes`. It doesn't parse like `array`.

Answer (score 0):

array() function does not parse strings.

```
array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple")
```

as you can see in the example there is not just a simple string, there are arguments.

Comment: Wrong answer everyone know what you have written

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you have posted wrong code.

```
$strng=array("Active Life" => "6","Arts & Entertainment" => "4","Beauty & Spa" => "3","Food & Drink" => "1","Hotels" => "10","Local Services" => "8","Nightlife" => "2","Pets" => "9","Public Services" => "7","Shopping" => "5");
 //$bussCatry=array($strng);

foreach($strng as $x=>$x_value)
   {
   echo( "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value);

  }
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Thanks.

Comment: I know this will work but in my question I have mentioned $strng is dynamically created string by which I will create array

Comment: @PrabhatShankar: though you can convert your string in this manner, if you feel hard to convert share your code here I will do it for you.

Comment: you have not given answer for string variable. I know above will work but if I have string variable which will contain the array value then how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), you can parse the string into tokens and then build your array as appropriate. Sorry it's a little messy, but it's a decent working starter.

```
<?php
define('STATE_WAITING_FOR_ARRAY',   1);
define('STATE_WAITING_FOR_KEY',     2);
define('STATE_WAITING_FOR_VALUE',   3);

$string = '"Active Life" => "6","Arts & Entertainment" => "4","Beauty & Spa" => "3","Food & Drink" => "1","Hotels" => "10","Local Services" => "8","Nightlife" => "2","Pets" => "9","Public Services" => "7","Shopping" => "5"';
$string = sprintf('<?php array(%s); ?>', $string);
$tokens = token_get_all($string);

$state = STATE_WAITING_FOR_ARRAY;

$array = array();

foreach($tokens as $token) {

    if( ! is_array($token)) {
        continue;
    }

    $name   = token_name($token[0]);
    $value  = $token[1];

    if(STATE_WAITING_FOR_ARRAY === $state && 'T_ARRAY' === $name) {
        $state = STATE_WAITING_FOR_KEY;
        continue;
    }

    if(STATE_WAITING_FOR_KEY === $state && 'T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING' === $name) {
        $state  = STATE_WAITING_FOR_VALUE;
        $key    = $value;
        continue;
    }

    if(STATE_WAITING_FOR_VALUE === $state && 'T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING' === $name) {
        $state          = STATE_WAITING_FOR_KEY;
        $array[$key]    = $value;
        $key            = null;
        continue;
    }
}


var_dump($array);

/*
    array(10) {
      [""Active Life""]=>
      string(3) ""6""
      [""Arts & Entertainment""]=>
      string(3) ""4""
      [""Beauty & Spa""]=>
      string(3) ""3""
      [""Food & Drink""]=>
      string(3) ""1""
      [""Hotels""]=>
      string(4) ""10""
      [""Local Services""]=>
      string(3) ""8""
      [""Nightlife""]=>
      string(3) ""2""
      [""Pets""]=>
      string(3) ""9""
      [""Public Services""]=>
      string(3) ""7""
      [""Shopping""]=>
      string(3) ""5""
    }
*/
```